# How to check that a parameter was supplied to a bash script

Tags: bash

I just want to check if one parameter was supplied in my bash script or not.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699576/validating-parameters-to-a-bash-script), but all the solutions seem to be unnecessarily complicated.

What's a simple solution to this simple problem that would make sense to a beginner?

Comment: ^answers from above possible duplicate are similar to the ones posted here including a comment about using the [[ -z  ]] test

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Use `$#` which is equal to the number of arguments supplied, e.g.:

```
if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]
then
  echo "Usage: ..."
  exit 1
fi
```

Word of caution: Note that inside a function this will equal the number of arguments supplied to the function rather than the script.

EDIT: As pointed out by [SiegeX](https://stackoverflow.com/users/207248/siegex) in bash you can also use arithmetic expressions in `(( ... ))`. This can be used like this:

```
if (( $# != 1 ))
then
  echo "Usage: ..."
  exit 1
fi
```

Comment: since this is `bash` question I would suggest `if (( $# != 1 ))`

Comment: For a range, a `case` statement may be more idiomatic. The syntax looks alien to beginners, though. `case $# in [123]) ;; *) echo fail >&2; exit 1;; esac`

Comment: Expressions in `[]` use `<`, `>`, `!=` and `==` for string comparisons and `-lt`, `-gt`, `-le`, `-ge`, `-ne` and `-eq` for arithmetic comparisons. Expressions in `(())` use `<`, `>`, `!=` and `==` for arithmetic comparisons. For more operators see [bash manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash).

Answer (score 42):

The accepted solution checks whether *parameters were set* by testing against the count of parameters given. If this is not the desired check, that is, if you want to check instead whether *a specific parameter was set*, the following would do it:

```
for i in "$@" ; do
    if [[ $i == "check parameter" ]] ; then
        echo "Is set!"
        break
    fi
done
```

Or, more compactly:

```
for i in "$@" ; do [[ $i == "check argument" ]] && echo "Is set!" && break ; done
```

Comment: I'm not sure your method is correct… for example: `./script check parameter` will succeed (which is incorrect).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf You are fully right. I edited with a solution that actually does the trick. Unfortunatelly with a loop.

Comment: you want it compact, there is this weird: `for i do [ "$i" == ...` probably just to confuse people [tldp](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/loops1.html#EX23)

Answer (score 14):

```
if (( "$#" != 1 )) 
then
    echo "Usage Info:…"
exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Thanks @SiegeX .. have updated the answer. Out of curiosity, any particular difference I should be aware of?

Comment: Only that it supports superior syntax such as `==` `!=` `<` `>` `<=` `>=` and it can also do boolean logic inside a single `(( ))` much like you can do in C