# Unix grep using Regex

Tags: regex, unix, grep

In Unix, I need an input validation which use grep:

`echo $INPUT| grep -E -q '^foo1foo2foo3' || echo "no"`

What I really need is if input doesn't match at least one of these values: `foo1` `foo2` or `foo3`, exit the program.

Source: syntax is taken from [Validating parameters to a Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699576/validating-parameters-to-a-bash-script)

Comment: Well the regex should probably be `^foo[123]$`.

Comment: Be careful to use `^` and `$` to anchor your matches if you want the *entire* value to match. Otherwise you could pass values like "foo14" and "aaafoo3zzz".

Comment: I was just copying from the source I found, I just need to match those words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really need grep? If you're scripting in bash:

```
[[ $INPUT == @(foo1|foo2|foo3) ]] || echo "no"
```

or

```
[[ $INPUT == foo[123] ]] || echo "no"
```

If you want "$INPUT **contains** one of those patterns

```
[[ $INPUT == *@(foo1|foo2|foo3)* ]] || echo "no"
```

Comment: Thank you, works great. I want to match exact so I'll use this `[[ $INPUT == foo[123] ]] || echo "no"`

Answer (score 4):

You need to use alternation:

```
echo "$INPUT" | grep -Eq 'foo1|foo2|foo3' || echo "no"
```

Comment: You missed `^`, I guess the OP needs a match on the beginning of the line.

Comment: Yes because OP wrote `if input doesn't match`, question didn't say if these values must be at the start of each line.

Comment: Thanks, this works perfect, but the other answer is shorter. I was just copying the code from the other source, hence the "echo"

Comment: If you're doing this against a file then `grep -Eq 'foo[1-3]' file` would be shortest

Answer (score 2):

Does this solve your problem:

```
echo $INPUT | grep -E 'foo1|foo2|foo3' || echo "no"
```

?